# Create Continuous-Time Waveform from Bit Sequence - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to ask the following: I have a row vector, let’s say v, which is actually a bit sequence which length 400 comprised of the concatenation of 40 sequences of length 10 where each one is eiter an all-ones sequence (i.e. 1111111111) or an all-zeros sequence (i.e. 0000000000). That is, this vector is something like [0000000000111111111111111111110000000000111111111100000000000000000000.........].

Now I want from this vector to geneate a Continuous-Time waveform, that is, as long as the value is 0, the value will be ketp to zero, when it goes to 1, the value of the waveform will also go to one and so on.

Any thought how I could do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually easier than what I was originally thinking. I just multiplied the vecot by 1. This did the job!